# PHP Connect to PostgreSQL using ssh2_tunnel

Tags: php, postgresql, debugging, ssh, remote-access

I'm busy trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database (running on a different server) after creating an ssh2_tunnel to that server.

The ssh2_tunnel seems to be working fine but my pg_connect is not working and I'm hoping I'm missing something small

```
<?php


ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


echo "<span>test script<br /></span>";


$connection = ssh2_connect('xxx.xx.xx.xx', 22);


if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'usname', './ssh_key.pub', './ssh_key', 'psword')) {
    echo "<span>Public Key Authentication Successful<br /></span>";
} else {
    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}


if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 5432)) {
    echo "<span>Tunnel Successful<br /></span>";
} else {
    die('Tunnel Failed');
};


// this is where it is failing and I'm not sure why
$string = "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=dbname user=dbuser password=dbpass";
$pgsqlcon = pg_connect($string) or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


?>
```

It is giving me the following error

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Another error from pg_last_error

```
Warning: pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet in /home/shoepack/public_html/admin_php_ssh/notused.php on line 26
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, it is not going to work this way. `ssh2_tunnel` creates a remote file pointer, aka resource, to be used in php functions like `fgets()`, `fwrite()` etc. It is not the same with ssh port forwarding.

You can try to open ssh tunnel on your php server form the shell: `ssh usname@xxx.xx.xx.xx -i ./ssh_key -L 5555:localhost:5432`. While the session is alive, you should be able to connect to the database from your php script as `pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5555 dbname=dbname user=dbuser password=dbpass");`

It is not for production use of course. What you need for production is to allow access to the database from your php application server. You may need to edit `postgresql.conf` to ensure the server is bound to correct interface, and `pg_hba.conf` to allow connections from your php host.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but removing the ssh accessibility and forwarding the postgresql port directly seems to work ok, do you have any advice on making the postgresql connection more secure though?

Comment: It depends on what you have now, your vectors, and how far you are ready to proceed. Some general advices: allow as little hosts to connect as possible, enable ssl, use pgcrypto.  Worth reading: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: This looks really useful I really appreciate the help