# php(ssh2, tunnel), I can't connect my remote mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, tunnel, ssh2

```
<?
   $server_ip = "my ubuntu ip";
   $server_port = "my ubuntu port";
   $server_user = 'my id';
   $user_pw = 'my pw';
   $connection = ssh2_connect($server_ip, $server_port);
   if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $server_user, $user_pw)) {
     echo "Authentication Successful!<br>";
   } else {
     echo "Authentication failed...";
   }

   $mysql_ip = '10.41.12.71';
   $mysql_default_port = '3306';

   $tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection,$mysql_ip,$mysql_default_port);
   if($tunnel) {
       echo "tunnel created<br>";
   }else {
       echo "tunnel creation failed";
       die();
   }
   
   $mysql_user = 'root';
   $mysql_user_pw = 'tkakcy159*';
   $dbname = 'test';
  //  $dbconn = mysqli_connect($tunnel,$mysql_user,$mysql_user_pw,$dbname);
   $dbconn = new mysqli($tunnel, $mysql_user, $mysql_user_pw, $dbname);
   if ($dbconn) {
    echo $dbname." connected<br>";
  } else {
    echo "DBConnection failed: " . $dbconn->connect_error;
  }

  // $insert_sql = " insert into test_table values('0001','wlsdhks0423'); ";
  // $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$insert_sql);
  // if($result) {
    //  echo "data insert success<br>";
    // }
    // else {
  //   echo "data insert failed : ".mysqli_error($dbconn);
  // }
  
  $select_sql = " select * from test_table; ";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$select_sql);

  if($result) {
    echo "selected rows : ".mysqli_num_rows($result)."<br>";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $key = $row['test_key'];
    $value = $row['test_value'];
    echo "key = ".$key."<br>value = ".$value;
  }else {
    echo mysqli_error($dbconn);
  }
   
   
   // phpinfo();
?>
```

This is my code. mysql is on ubuntu device.
And I think I can access ubuntu, but mysql connection is failed

this php's output is

```
Authentication Successful!
tunnel created
test connected
```

and if i use this line

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($tunnel,$mysql_user,$mysql_user_pw,$dbname);
```

then output is

```
Authentication Successful!
tunnel created
DBConnection failed:
```

The obvious thing is that $connection and $tunnel has no problem.
I had tested them. And works well.

Comment: test_table has data. And I can't get error msg from mysqli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Connect to PostgreSQL using ssh2\_tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494865/php-connect-to-postgresql-using-ssh2-tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

This is an exact duplicate of the postgresql question because they both exist for the same reason. You're both trying to connect a service over a SSH Tunnel by using `ssh2_tunnel` incorrectly.

`ssh2_tunnel` returns a `resource` aka a `file pointer`

Answer (score 0):

The ssh2_tunnel() return a socket object which means you can operate this socket object just like you use standard socket function.

I have such code:

```
    fwrite($ssh_tunnel, $db_password);
    while (!feof($ssh_tunnel)) {
          echo fgets($ssh_tunnel, 1280);
    }
```

and I get such result:

```
a 5.5.5-10.3.34-MariaDB-cll-lve��=^Aile5x����}.hBNEM5_^:Gmysql_native_password!��#08S01Got packets out of order
```

I think `fwrite` can send something to such tunnel we have created, so I am currently figuring out what data should be sent to.